# Furnace is short cycling after running continuously

Tags: furnace

My thermostat stopped working, so I tried to hard wire the connection to make it through the night. When I woke up the furnace was off and trying to start it now the inducer seems to turn on for a few seconds and then off again, and repeats.

How can I fix this or determine what is wrong?

Comment: One (of many) possibilities: Furnace ran continuously so long that it overheated, but along the way something went wrong which is now causing the short-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

How is your furnace fueled? If you have a pilot light, is it a simple light (with a lighter or match) and ignite or spark and ignite (like a gas grill) or does the unit have an electronic ignition?
What I’m getting at is your unit may have timed out and automatically extinguished the pilot light.
Depending on the type of pilot light you may have to find the thermocouple… to the right (usually) you’ll find the pilot light position/location. Typically you’ll have to manually engage ( turn to pilot, push and hold continuously while either relighting the pilot light or pushing the red spark igniter, until the pilot is burning on its own)
If you have an electronic pilot light, you’ll have to power down at the breaker/fuse box for at least 90 seconds (I usually wait about 5 minutes). The thermostat(s) all have to be turned off or way down( below the temperature in the home/interior. You may also have to find  the pilot on/off switch located in the control box usually near the pilot light position. Turn the switch off for at least 90 seconds (again I wait about five minutes.
Once you have everything turned off and waited the allotted time for the unit to reset and most importantly allowing any stagnant fuel to dissipate.
First turn the pilot control switch on. Move on to the breaker/fuse box and reestablish the power (replace fuse or turn breaker switch on.
Once you have set the furnace and power source on, then turn you thermostat up/on (I usually start by setting the thermostat at least 10 degrees above the current temperature.
You should hear the furnace eventually ignite and typically you’ll also hear the blower within the furnace.

Comment: What's up with the picture?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact    Same thought here....probably an oops!

Comment: Yes. Definitely the wrong picture. My apologies. I’m new to this forum… I thought I was setting up a profile.